# LINQ Join List of List

Tags: c#, linq, list

Using LINQ, how can I join (Inner Join) list of list datas

Example datas:

```
List<List<string>> datas1 = new List<List<string>>();
datas1.add(new List() { "1", "Item 1" });
datas1.add(new List() { "2", "Item 2" });
datas1.add(new List() { "3", "Item 3" });

List<List<string>> datas2 = new List<List<string>>();
datas1.add(new List() { "1", "20" });
datas1.add(new List() { "2", "10" });
```

Expected Result in `List<List<string>>`:

```
List("1", "Item 1", "20");
List("2", "Item 2", "10");
```

I try

```
var result = datas1
      .Join(datas2, d1 => datas1[0], d2 => datas2[0], (d1, d2) => { d1 })
      .ToList();
```

I get Empty result, then try :

```
var result = datas1
          .Join(datas2, d1 => datas1[0][0], d2 => datas2[0][0], (d1, d2) => { d1 })
          .ToList();
```

I get duplicate result for each datas1.

Comment: You only add items to `datas1` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the parameters within your lambda expressions in the joins - you've used `datas1[0]` and `datas2[0]` instead of `d1[0]` and `d2[0]`. Additionally, your projection to the result doesn't give you want you've said you want.

Your query should be like this:

```
var result = datas1
      .Join(datas2, d1 => d1[0], d2 => d2[0], 
            (d1, d2) => new List<string> { d1[0], d1[1], d2[1] })
      .ToList();
```

Or you could use a query expression:

```
var result = (from d1 in datas1
              join d2 in datas2 on d1[0] equals d2[0]
              select new List<string> { d1[0], d1[1], d2[1] })
             .ToList();
```

(Personally I'd stick with the non query expression version in this case, I think.)

However, it would be better not to have a `List<List<string>>` though, but to use appropriate types for all your data - possibly with an anonymous type for the result. For example, you might then have something like:

```
var result = datas1
      .Join(datas2, d1 => d1.Id, d2 => d2.Id, 
            (d1, d2) => new { d1.Id, d1.Name, d2.Description })
      .ToList();
```

You'd also then be able to store numbers in `int` values rather than in strings...

Comment: I try with parameter too same as your code but without new List<string>, and get empty result too.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Sample data
List<List<string>> datas1 = new List<List<string>>();
datas1.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "Item 1" });
datas1.Add(new List<string>() { "2", "Item 2" });
datas1.Add(new List<string>() { "3", "Item 3" });

List<List<string>> datas2 = new List<List<string>>();
datas2.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "20" });
datas2.Add(new List<string>() { "2", "10" });
```

You need to join `datas1` *and* `datas2` `on d1[0][0] equals d2[0][0]` as follows:

```
//Query
var result = (from d1 in datas1
              join d2 in datas2 on d1[0][0] equals d2[0][0]
              select new List<string> { d1[0], d1[1], d2[1] })
             .ToList();
```